# How to get if an url is 404 or 301 in crawler4j

Tags: crawler4j

Is it possible to get if an URL is 404 or 301 in crawler4j ?

```
@Override
    public void visit(Page page) {
        String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
        System.out.println("URL: " + url);

        if (page.getParseData() instanceof HtmlParseData) {
            HtmlParseData htmlParseData = (HtmlParseData) page.getParseData();
            String text = htmlParseData.getText();
            String html = htmlParseData.getHtml();
            List<WebURL> links = htmlParseData.getOutgoingUrls();

            System.out.println("Text length: " + text.length());
            System.out.println("Html length: " + html.length());
            System.out.println("Number of outgoing links: " + links.size());
        }
    }
```

I use this in the crawler code .Can anyone tell me how ?

Answer (score 2):

As Crawler4j Version 3.3 (Feb 2012 released)  - Crawler4j supportting for handling http status codes for fetched pages.

to visit StatusHandlerCrawlerExample [click.](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/?r=0161a713f264d504013c83f3152c2cd40366a790#crawler4j/examples/statushandler)

Also you can parse pages by using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) (Java HTML Parser, with best of DOM, CSS, and jquery). And there is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518972/open-a-connection-with-jsoup-get-status-code-and-parse-document) - shows how to download a page from given URL and getting page status code. I think you should use Crawler4j for crawling and Jsoup for page fetching.