# using cookie to access a website

Tags: android, cookies

I am trying create a webview in android to access in to a website, I made some code to get cookie  from the website by username and password. And the result I got is:

```
[version: 0][name: MoodleSession][value: arkitgq9pabpnjka5l0qbj75u1][domain: 192.168.1.105][path: /moodle/][expiry: null]
```

now I don't know how to use it to login in to website. please help me. 
thank.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty straightforward.

**Short Answer**

Here is snippets of code that does this task:

When we get 1st response from login page, we store Cookies by this way:

```
List<Cookie> mCookies = null;

 ...

mCookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

Next time on login, we create `CookieStore`

```
 CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
```

and store our Cookies:

```
for(Cookie cook : mCookies){
   cookieStore.addCookie(cook); 
 }
```

After, provide store to http client:

```
httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
```

That's all.

**Unitest that connects to captive portal with login**

Its working code, just in case if you are interesting to see how it works

```
private static String URL = "";
    List<Cookie> mCookies = null;
    String mHost = null;



    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        super.setUp();  


        MessageItf imp = this;
        LoggerImp.implMessge(imp);  

        mContext = getContext();

        assertNotNull(mContext);

        URL = mContext.getString(R.string.URL); 

    }



    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();               
    }



    public void redirect(String url){

        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;
        //      boolean success = false;

        try {           
            Log.d("test_runner","send Data started");


            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            int m_timeout = 60000;
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, m_timeout);            
            HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 8192);

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, m_timeout);    // connection timeout
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, m_timeout);            // socket timeout


            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(); 
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, context);


            mCookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

            if (mCookies.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("test_runner", "Cookies: None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < mCookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + mCookies.get(i).toString());
                    Log.d("test_runner", "Cookies: [" + i + "]" + mCookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }

            int statusCode =  response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Header[] headers = response.getHeaders("Location");

                if (headers != null && headers.length != 0) {
                    String newUrl =  headers[headers.length - 1].getValue();

                    redirect(newUrl);                   

                } 
            }   
            else{ // status 200

                HttpHost currentHost = (HttpHost)  context.getAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);

                mHost = currentHost.toURI();

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {


                    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr, 1024 * 4);
                    String line = null;
                    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        //System.out.println("Data Sender: " +  line);

                        buff.append(line).append("\n");

                    }
                    is.close();

                } else {
                    Log.d("test_runner", "Data Sender: response is null");
                }

                Log.d("test_runner", "Output: " +  buff);


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("test_runner", ThrowableToString.fromThrowableToString(e));
        }

        if (httpclient != null) {           
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }       

    }


    public void test_runner(){
        String url = "http://google.com";

        redirect(url);      
    }




    private void doPost(String formAction, String inputRootValue,
            String inputRootName, String onSubmitName, String onSubmitVal) {

        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;

        try {  

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            int m_timeout = 60000;
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, m_timeout);            
            HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 8192);

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, m_timeout);    // connection timeout
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, m_timeout);            // socket timeout

            CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); 

            for(Cookie cook : mCookies){
                cookieStore.addCookie(cook); 
            }

            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

            if(mHost != null){
                formAction =  mHost + "/www/" + formAction; 
            }
            else{
                formAction =  "http://localhost.ap.coova.org/www/" + formAction; 
            }




            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(formAction);

            List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(inputRootName, inputRootValue));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(onSubmitName, onSubmitVal));


            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));




            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                if(statusCode != 200){

                }

                Log.d("test_runner", "response.getStatusLine: " + response.getStatusLine());

                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = null;
                while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    //System.out.println("Data Sender: " +  line);

                    buff.append(line).append("\n");


                }
                is.close();

                //entity.consumeContent();
            } else {

            }

            Log.d("test_runner", "response: " + buff.toString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("test_runner", ThrowableToString.fromThrowableToString(e));
        }

        if (httpclient != null) {
            // resource cleanup
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }

    }
```

Comment: your code really help me, thank you so much, I just want to ask one more thing, how do we can use this cookie to get document type on a website by jsoup connect?

Comment: You welcome. If you found my answer helpful, please vote up, About your question, i never did that so cant answer but try to see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518972/open-a-connection-with-jsoup-get-status-code-and-parse-document/10519976#10519976